# Setting the rank of a user-defined verb in J

Tags: tacit-programming, j

Here's a function to calculate the digital sum of a number in J:

```
digitalSum =: +/@:("."0)@":
```

If I use `b.` to query the rank of this verb, I get `_ 1 _`, i.e., infinite. (We can ignore the dyadic case since `digitalSum` is not dyadic.)

I would like the monadic rank of this verb to be 0, as reported by `b.`. The only way I know of to do this is to use a "shim", e.g.,

```
ds =: +/@:("."0)@":
digitalSum =: ds"0
```

This works great, but I want to know whether it's the only way to do this, or if there's something else I'm missing.

**Clarification**

I just discovered how to change the rank of a verb that's defined thus:

```
digits =: 3 : 0 "0
    "."0@": y
)
```

Notice the `"0` after the declaring `3 : 0`. You can put any adverb or conjunction you wish, and it will be applied to the verb as a whole. Pretty cool stuff!

Comment: Yet again, I may have answered my own question:

`digitalSum =: (+/@:("."0)@":)"0`

However, perhaps there's another way, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`digitalSum =: (+/@:("."0)@":)"0` is how I would define it as well. Using `"` to change rank is pretty standard and works on parenthesized tacit trains.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that it would work on trains, but it now seems pretty obvious.